# setting an entity property using a form and controller

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

In a Spring MVC application using hibernate, I am encountering an error when the user tries to specify the `location` (entity is `FacilityAddress`) of an `appointment` (entity is `Encounter`) using a JSP.  Specifically, the property `Encounter.location` needs to be set by the JSP.  The list of possible locations is given to the user by a model attribute `praddrs`, which is correctly populated in the JSP form by the GET method in the controller.

Can someone show me how to get this functionality to work properly without throwing an error?

I can create the `400 error` when I add the following line of code to my JSP:

```
<form:select path="location" items="${praddrs}" size="3" style="min-width:200px"/>
```

The `400 error` states:

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

There is no stack trace in the eclipse console.

I have read a number of other stack overflow postings on this, and have done google searches along with tinkering with my code, but I cannot seem to isolate the solution for my unique situation.  Can someone show me how to get past this error?

Here is the form in the JSP:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="encounter" method="${method}" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group" id="patient">
        <label class="control-label">Patient </label>
        <c:out value="${encounter.patient.firstName} ${encounter.patient.lastName}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group" id="datetime">
        <label class="control-label">Date and Time </label>
        <joda:format value="${encounter.dateTime}" style="SM"/>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Office</label>
        <form:select path="location" items="${praddrs}" size="3" style="min-width:200px"/>
    </div>

    <petclinic:inputField label="Duration (mins)" name="numMins"/>

    <td>
    </td>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${encounter['new']}">
                <button type="submit">Add Encounter</button>
            </c:when>
            <c:otherwise>
                <button type="submit">Update Encounter</button> <h3>    Link to delete will go here.</h3>
            </c:otherwise>
        </c:choose>
    </div>
</form:form>
```

Here is the controller method for handling the `POST` for this JSP:

```
//THIS IS THE METHOD THAT HANDLES THE FORM
@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/encounters/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String processCreationForm(@ModelAttribute("encounter") Encounter encounter, @RequestParam("providerId") int providerId, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    System.out.println("inside processCreationForm() ");
    System.out.println("encounter.getDateTime() is: "+encounter.getDateTime());
    new EncounterValidator().validate(encounter, result);
    Provider myprovider = this.clinicService.findProviderById(providerId);
    encounter.addProvider(myprovider);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println("about to return errors. ");
        return "encounters/createOrUpdateEncounterForm";
    } else {
        System.out.println("about to save encounter ");
        this.clinicService.saveEncounter(encounter);
        System.out.println("done saving encounter.");
        status.setComplete();
        System.out.println("finished status.setComplete()");
        return "redirect:/encounters?encounterID={encounterId}";
    }
}
```

For reference, the controller method for handling the JSP's `GET` is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/patients/{patientId}/encounters/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String initCreationForm(@PathVariable("patientId") int patientId, @RequestParam("providerId") int prid, org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest webRequest, Map<String, Object> model) {
    Patient patient = this.clinicService.findPatientById(patientId);
    LocalDate theday = new LocalDate(webRequest.getParameter("day"));
    LocalTime thetime = new LocalTime(webRequest.getParameter("time"));
    DateTime thedatetime = theday.toDateTime(thetime);
    this.clinicService.findFacilityAddressByProviderId(prid);
    Encounter encounter = new Encounter();
    encounter.setDateTime(thedatetime);
    patient.addEncounter(encounter);
    ArrayList<FacilityAddress> praddrs = (ArrayList<FacilityAddress>) this.clinicService.findFacilityAddressByProviderId(prid);
    Provider pr = clinicService.findProviderById(prid);
    model.put("encounter", encounter);
    model.put("praddrs", praddrs);
    model.put("pr", pr);
    return "encounters/createOrUpdateEncounterForm";
}
```

I HAVE POSTED THE ENTITY CODE TO A FILE SHARING SITE SO THAT THIS POSTING CAN BE EASIER TO READ.  You can read the entity code by clicking on the following links:

The `Encounter` entity code can be read [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/HZa6rUaQ2rYT6fZFUGqD?b=5kGXnbu644ibC8sVfoQU).
The `FacilityAddress` entity code can be read [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/V4xBVwm86ly5A5Lg4yGF?b=UXj2ryTjLo0wAZ0rAlYQ).
The BaseEntity code can be read [at this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/rYHzIV7P3fQKZ4qEalZD?b=ndIjMOqNwwx0mryvcvHM).

Comment: Probably because you defined providerId as a @RequestParam but didn't put it in the form.

Comment: @developerwjk `providerId` is in the url string. And the error can be removed by deleting the line `<form:select path="location" items="${praddrs}" size="3" style="min-width:200px"/>` from the JSP.  If you still think the `@RequestParam` is the problem, can you show how to fix the code to solve the problem?

Comment: If you remove the form the error goes away?  So you aren't accessing the servlet via the form submission? I'm totally confused by your question then.

Comment: @developerwjk If I remove the specified line of code `<form:select path="location" items="${praddrs}" size="3" style="min-width:200px"/>` , the controller POST method is allowed to run, and towards the end of the method, there is an error related to not having a value for the column in the database that maps location. The given line of code in JSP triggers the 400 error.  My question is how to find a better way to let the user choose the location for their encounter.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing "location" to "location.id"?

```
<form:select path="location.id" items="${praddrs}" size="3" style="min-width:200px"/>
```